# Android Alarm Manager : BroadcastReceiver components are not allowed to register to receive intents

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am using android Alarm Manager to schedule SMS. When Alarm time reach and Manager tries to send the SMS it gives me following Exception.

"Android.content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException: BroadcastReceiver components are not allowed to register to receive intents."

I tried to figure out this, but still im in the same position.

please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You will get that when you call `registerReceiver()` on the `Context` supplied to `onReceive()`. However, I have no idea why you would even be doing that in this case, as you should not need to call `registerReceiver()` to send an SMS. Please edit your question to paste in the code that is raising this error.

Comment: Thank u. I removed the registerReceiver()...Then Its ok...

Answer (score 11):

You can use this.

```
context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver();
```

Comment: Yuo're my savior!